# Есть ли способ узнать, какие ключи типа Symbol есть в объекте?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Мне нужен способ узнать, какие Symbol используется в качестве имени свойств в объекте. Цикл `for...in` игнорирует ключи типа Symbol, как и `Object.keys()`.

Comment: вы бы хоть пример какой привели. Какие то сиволы, в каком то объекте кем то игнорируются - как это понять?

Comment: Уточнил вопрос.

Answer (score 5):

Если я правильно понимаю, вам нужен метод [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols) или более общий [`Reflect.ownKeys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/ownKeys).

Comment: спасибо вам большое

Comment: И вам спасибо на добром слове)

Comment: Я немного подправил вопрос, чтобы он стал яснее и однозначнее, легче искался в будущем и его не закрыли.